# What is the distribution of $S_n$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $x_1 ,\ldots ,x_n $ be a random sample of size $n$ taken from the generalized inverted exponential distribution with pdf $$f(x|\lambda , \theta )=\frac{\lambda}{\theta}x^{-2}\exp \left(-\frac{\lambda}{x}\right)\left[1-\exp \left(-\frac{\lambda}{x}\right)\right]^{\frac{1}{\theta}-1}, \; x>0,\; \lambda ,\theta >0 .$$ What is the distribution of $$S_n =-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln \left(1-\exp \left(-\frac{\lambda}{x_i }\right)\right)?$$
What is $E(S_n)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really about [distribution-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-theory)?

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry, You are right. I'm new in statistics. I'll edit it.

Comment: @M.Ramana: After standard calculations, you find that

$$Y=-\ln\left( 1-\exp(-\lambda/X)  \right)\sim \text{Exp}(1/\theta)$$

where  $\text{Exp}(1/\theta)$ is exponential density with mean $\theta$


$$f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-y/\theta}$$

$y>0$


Thus $S_n$ has a gamma distribution. Understood this, $\mathbb{E}[S_n]$ immediately follows.

Show your efforts and, in case you get stuck, I will post the correct calculations

Comment: @tommik Thank you very much for your great comment. Could you please tell me how we know a variable has a special distribution? For example, how can I show that $Y$ has the exponential distribution? By computing $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$?

Comment: @tommik I'm new at statistics, but I am very curious about knowing how to recognize a distribution for a given variable. I was wondering if you could tell me about it.

Comment: @M.Ramana: please find my answer below. As you can see, due to the "closing vote" in your question, my answer get a "-1". So, if I do not receive an accepted answer/ upvote I will delete it

Comment: @tommik Thank you so much for your help. I've learned great points from your answer.

Comment: @tommik: I'm not your downvoter but as the Question lacks context, I'm voting to close it (to encourage the OP to do the necessary research to ask in a way that meets site standards).  In jumping to the conclusion of $S_n$ having a gamma distribution, you have alerted the OP to the value of recognizing what you called "standard calculations", but someone "new at statistics" needs a bit of grinding away to become as proficient as you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f_X(x)=\frac{\lambda}{\theta}\frac{1}{x^2}e^{-\lambda/x}[1-e^{-\lambda/x}]^{1/\theta-1}$$

set

$$Y=-\ln(1-e^{-\lambda/X})$$

that is

$$x=-\frac{\lambda}{\ln(1-e^{-y})}$$

$$x'=\lambda\frac{e^{-y}}{(1-e^{-y})\ln^2(1-e^{-y})}$$

the use the formula

$$f_Y(y)=f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right|$$

substitute, simplify the expression and get the result.

your random variable $S_n$ is the sum of $n$ independent exponential thus it is a Gamma

$$S_n\sim\text{Gamma}[n;\theta]$$

with $\theta$ as scale parameter, thus its expectation is

$$\mathbb{E}[S_n]=n\theta$$

and variance

$$\mathbb{V}[S_n]=n\theta^2$$